# How can I change only vowels from uppercase to lowercase and vice versa (MATLAB)

Tags: string, matlab

I have to change every vowel on a string to upper or lower case depending what it already is.. so "UPPERCASE lowercase" becomes "uPPeRCaSe lOwErcAsE"

So far I have had no success with this aproach

```
str=  'UPPERCASE lowercase';
vow = 'aeiou';
vowm = 'AEIOU';

for k = 1:5

if str(str == vow(k))
str(str == vow(k))= vowm(k);
else 
    if str(str == vowm(k))
        str(str == vowm(k))= vow(k);
```

Expected output: "uPPeRCaSe lOwErcAsE"

Actual output: "uPPERCASE lOwErCAsE"

I am extremely new to matlab and im kinda lost.
i aprecciate your help

Answer (score 5):

Use [`ismember`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to find all occurrences of each type of vowels (uppercase or lowercase), and then [`upper`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/upper.html) and [`lower`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lower.html) to convert them:

```
str = 'UPPERCASE lowercase';    %// original string
indl = ismember(str, 'aeiou');  %// locations of lowercase vowels
indu = ismember(str, 'AEIOU');  %// locations of uppercase vowels
str(indl) = upper(str(indl));   %// convert from lower to upper
str(indu) = lower(str(indu));   %// convert from upper to lower
```

Answer (score 3):

As listed in the question, I am assuming the following as the inputs  -

```
%// Inputs
str=  'UPPERCASE lowercase'
vow = 'aeiou'
vowm = 'AEIOU'
```

**Approach #1**

One approach based on [`changem`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/changem.html) that is used to substitute values -

```
%// Create maps from input string to reflect changes from lower to upper
%// and vice versa
map1 = changem(str,vowm,vow)
map2 = changem(str,vow,vowm)

%// Find indices to be changed for lower to upper change and vice versa change
idx1 = find(map1~=str)
idx2 = find(map2~=str)

%// Selectively change input string based on the indices to be changed and maps
str(idx1) = map1(idx1)
str(idx2) = map2(idx2)
```

---

**Approach #2**

With [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
%// Find indices to be changed for lower to upper change and vice versa change
[~,idx1] = find(bsxfun(@eq,str,vow'))
[~,idx2] = find(bsxfun(@eq,str,vowm'))

%// Selectively change input string based on the indices to be changed and maps
str(idx1) = str(idx1)-32
str(idx2) = str(idx2)+32
```

Comment: What is the advantage of using `+-32` compared to `upper` and `lower` in the second approach? I know it is a different way of doing it but `upper` and `lower` seems a lot more intuitive.

Comment: @kkuilla Not that intuitive for sure, but I guess I wanted to have something different or else these two answers, well at least 50% of them would look the same :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use **[regular expressions](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html)**
 as well.

I don't know how different this is to the other answers though...

```
str=  'UPPERCASE lowercase';
vow = '[aeiou]';
vowm = '[AEIOU]';

indl = regexp(str,vow);
indu = regexp(str,vowm);

str(indl) = upper(str(indl));
str(indu) = lower(str(indu));
```

Comment: Thank you. I think it would be quite slow for a large dataset though.

Comment: Which part do you think would make it slow?

Comment: Yes, `regexp` has a name of being slow. I have never timed it myself, though

Comment: It might be ok in this instance as the regexp isnt' too complex.